# With VBA get Internet explorer to select item from list

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Good Day,

I've searched for answers and solutions proveded on this site did not seem to help including selectedIndex and looping through arrays

I've got the following HTML code making up a table from which I want to select the second option "Vorige week"

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" title=""  class="mstrListBlock" 
id="id_mstr51" style="display: table; width: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="mstrListBlockCell">
<span class="">
<div class="mstrListBlockCaption" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="mstrListBlockHeader" style="display: none;">
<div style="" class="mstrListBlockContents" 
id="ListBlockContents_id_mstr51">
<div oncontextmenu="return 
mstr.behaviors.Generic.oncontextmenu(arguments[0], self, 'id_mstr51');" 
onmouseup="try{mstr.$obj('id_mstr51').focus();}catch(localerr){}; return 
mstr.behaviors.Generic.clearBrowserHighlights(self)" onmousedown="var retVal 
= mstr.behaviors.ListView.onmousedown(arguments[0], self, 'id_mstr51'); 
try{mstr.$obj('id_mstr51').focus();}catch(localerr){}; return retVal" 
ondblclick="return mstr.behaviors.ListView.ondblclick(arguments[0], self, 
'id_mstr51')" class="mstrListBlockListContainer" id="id_mstr51ListContainer" 
style="display: block;">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Huidige Week">
<div class="mstrListBlockItemSelected" title="Vorige Week">
<div class="mstrBGIcon_fi mstrListBlockItemName" style="background-position: 
2px 50%; padding-left: 23px;">Vorige Week</div>
</div>
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Afgesloten 4 Weken">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Afgesloten 8 Weken">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Huidige Periode">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Vorige Periode">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Afgesloten 2 Perioden">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Selectie Datum Hiërarchie. Aangepast 
wegens IServer crash icm. Metric prompts.">
<div class="mstrListBlockItem" title="Gisteren">
```

I think my problem is in deciding which element I need to use to get the desired outcome

```
Sub JDWReport()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "URL"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("Uid").Value = "username"
objIE.document.getElementById("Pwd").Value = "password"
objIE.document.getElementById("3054").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.navigate "URL2"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.document.getElementsClassName("mstrBGIcon_fi 
mstrListBlockItemName")(0).Click

objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

See code above which I'm currently using.
It gets stuck with the line objIE.document.getElementsClassName("mstrBGIcon_fi 
    mstrListBlockItemName")(0).Click
I tried changing this line to different elements based on the HTML code and use .click .selectedindex=2 but those won't work.

```
<div class="mstrListBlockItemSelected" title="Vorige Week">
```

Currently it says mstrListBlockItemSelected, however, when first navigating to the site, the class is defined as the rest, mstrListBlockItem.

It will only change to selected if you click on the item in question (from a list of items). My ultimate goal would be to get the class with title "Vorige Week" to change from mstrListBlockItem to mstrListBlockItemSelected.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please share your VBA code. What is the desired outcome? And can you share the URL?

Comment: 1. **Any error?** 2. What is **the present output**? 3. And, like QHarr asked, what is **the wanted output?** 4. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using HTML Table and create DIV's in that.

I try to search and find that there is no any method or property is available to select the text in DIV.

I suggest you to use any HTML control to select its value. For example "Select option".

You can try to create drop down using select and then use the code below to select any value in it.

```html
Sub Select_Item()
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\element.html"  
       
       While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set post = .Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCycleID")
       
       For Each elem In post.getElementsByTagName("option")
            If InStr(elem.Value, "10") > 0 Then elem.Selected = True: Exit For
        Next elem
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an attribute = value CSS selector:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vorige Week']").Selected = True
```

Or

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vorige Week']").Click
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, for taking the time to give me a possible solution. Unfortunately, both do not seem to work. The first option gives me an Error 438, "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method". The second does nothing and continues the code as if nothing happened.

Comment: Ok. Will get back to you later.